# Cancel POSIX thread after a common work is done

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

There are multiple threads working on a task. Once a thread succeeds all of the thread should be canceled, as the work is accomplished. How can i cancel the other threads once one thread has terminated successfully ? Who will call `pthread_cancel ()` and how will the successful thread tell `main` or the thread which spawned it (return value ?).

**UPDATE**

I do not want to simply call `exit` as i want now some control. For example after the threads are canceled , i will process the found result by the successful thread and possible do some more processing, or simply want to keep the process running for some more work.

Comment: Why do you need multiple threads for this task, if you're going to throw away the work done by all but one of them?  Just do the work once in one thread.

Comment: say, i have a huge list to search linearly, i will pass segments of lists to different threads, and once one finds a match, returns. others are cancelled.

Comment: I guess that makes sense in a context where a brute-force search is the only option, but if you have any structure at all in your data, there are better algorithms.

Comment: my application uses brute force to generate all possible valid passwords, or read passwords from a dictionary and check with hashes, therefore i need to cancel threads once one thread has succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could choose a simple scheme where main does everything.

Have `main` start all the threads and do a `down` on some semaphore. When a thread finishes the task, do an `up` on that semaphore. When main is unlocked it can `pthread_cancel` all the threads (and then `pthread_join` to make sure).

This way `main` starts and stops all the threads so it should be pretty simple.

Comment: yes, my design is a main based one and , this is a good idea. Anything could be done with signals ?

Comment: @phoxis To be sure, you can send a signal to a thread using `pthread_kill`. Still in this rule I feel it would be messy (I can't think of an easy way of leaving the thread from a signal handler). But don't take my word for it, I always shy away from signals.

Comment: in the case of main spawning childs , i like the mutex solution, and i will use it. I asked about signals when it is the case that the threads are being spawned recursively or randomly without any common parent, in that case signals could work. Or is there other way to handle cancellation of such random spawning ?

Comment: @phoxis Sure there is. To be able to cancel a thread, you simply need its `pthread_t id`. Now if you would have a global (and thread-safe) data structure holding these ids.. :-)

Comment: yes, okay, then i need to take them as global. okay great. thanks for lighting the bulb (the mutex solution).

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to call `exit()` which terminates the process along with all the threads. It can be called from any thread.

Another way is to have your main thread spawn and wait on the worker threads, and once one of the worker threads has completed either:

- tell nicely the other threads to terminate and wait till they do, or
- abruptly [`pthread_cancel()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html) them. By default threads are created with `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, which means they won't terminate until they call any of the cancellation point functions, see [Thread Cancellation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_05) for a good description. So, if you threads are doing some long computations you might want to set their cancellation state to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` to terminate the thread immediately, see [pthread_setcanceltype](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_setcancelstate.html).

Comment: yes, that is one way which i was using till before posting this, but i want now some more control. For example after the threads are canceled , i will process the found result by the successful thread and possible do some more processing.

Comment: You can do signals, but why bother? `pthread_cancel()` is drastic enough.

Comment: Note that when async cancellation is enabled, you are not allowed to call **any** library functions, not even `strlen` or such. The only allowable library action is disabling asynchronous cancellation.

Comment: Interesting. Care to post a link with details?